# Status bar with wrong background color

Tags: ios, xcode

In storyboard I have:

[image]

but after compile, it looks like:

[image]

Why background of status bar is white instead of red?

Comment: Add this `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` in `AppDelegate didFinishLaunching` delegate method.

Comment: You may have to set the backgroundColor for the view that holds the tableView to your chosen color. This view shows through the statusbar

Answer (score 1):

This is because the status bar don't have an color it depends on the background in this case your view behind it, you only change the navigation bar tint you can do :-

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate

Or just simply hide the status bar in Your View controller by :-

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

> NOTE

setStatusBarStyle: is deprecated in IOS 9.0

> USE

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```